# How colon and semicolon differs in linux command?

Tags: linux

How the colon and semicolon differs in the following linux commands?

```
    who am i: 

    who am i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it really doesn't matter much.

Usually, a `;` is used to mark the end of a command in certain situations:

```
if [[ ... ]]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

The `who` command, however, will produce the same output regardless of what the two words on the command line is.  The `:` is not special:

```
$ who am i

$ who makes dinner

$ who ano.L::e se=el
```

These will produce the exact same output.

So, to answer the question:

1. The `:` is part of the word `i:` and doesn't mean anything special here.
2. The semicolon marks the end of the command, and is not needed since there is no other command on the line after it.